# Minecraft Launcher invisible; preview works, alt-tab/alt-space doesn't

Tags: unity, java, minecraft

This may be a problem with java applications in general.

Problem began at some point after a restart, subsequent restarts have not fixed it, nor has uninstalling/reinstalling java (openJDK-7) and the minecraft launcher itself.

When I try to run it (from the console, using java -jar launcher.jar) the normal text pops up in the console, but the window for the launcher does not appear. An icon for it pops up on the left side of the screen, and if I hold alt and hit tab, it will show up in the list of available programs. Right clicking on it while holding alt will show what the launcher should look like, and clicking on it will cause the active window to lose focus, but will not bring the launcher into focus. The launcher is absent from the Master+W screen, and attempting to resize/maximize the window from alt-space causes Unity to seize up for a moment before returning to normal function.

Anyone have a clue what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just realized the problem. Had an Oculus Rift plugged into a USB port, and apparently this screws with graphical programs if and only if you had it plugged in at startup, whether or not it has been given power. Removing it and restarting corrected the issue.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't at the time this was posted initially and forgot about it over time.

Answer (score 0):

You could try if it works when using java 8 (this is a universe packet).

Or try [multimc](https://multimc.org/) , it helps me a great deal with crashes and all kind of stuff on modded minecraft. but works for vanilla as well.

Comment: Weird, for some reason your answer didn't appear for me until just after I posted mine. Thank you for taking the time to answer, but it turned out to be a hardware issue, kind of.